# E3D v6 oozing / dripping

Tags: extruder, e3d-v6

edit:
custom printer with 2 hitends (generic ptfe lined and genuine e3d v6 all metal). verified same temperature. e3d v6 oozes to the point that its unusable, generic works well.

steps taken 
verified temps are identical with external probe
changed nozzles
rebuilt by to ensure no gaps 
checked v6 hearsink cooling
changed retractions. settings.

original:
I've got a custom dual extruder machine - I've calibrated the temperatures of both hotends so I know the temperatures are very accurate.

One is a regular hotend similar to an Ender 3 setup and the other is a genuine E3D v6 - and I've checked the assembly many times.

At 190 °C, my external mp probe reads 190 °C on both. with PLA at 190 °C in the Ender 3 style hotend, pushing filament through by hand is smooth but requires some push and the oozing stops very soon after. on the E3D hotend, no effort is required and it will continue to ooze filament for quite a while.

I've checked and double checked the temperature, changed nozzles, checked and double checked assembly and Bowden tube seating position and I'm at a loss as to how to get this E3D v6 to stop oozing because it seems to just drip  even at low temperatures, retractions do nothing and the prints with that extruder are messy.

Any advice on how to get this thing to stop oozing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When a hotend is hot, filament leaks out, that is just a given. Retraction and standby temperature (considerably lower than the printing temperature) can be used to fight the oozing. I have non-genuine E3D v6 hotends which also ooze at print temperature and filled nozzle chamber, retraction helps a little, there is always molten plastic that will come out. You're just lucky one hotend doesn't leak.

Comment: This has been asked before, so don't be surprised if the community will vote for a duplicate, see e.g. [When dwelling G4, my printer is oozing, how can i stop that?](/q/7509/) or this one [Ender 3 extrudes plastic whilst at standstill, and while moving to start of print](/q/7484).

Comment: Without retraction, oozing is unavoideable. Retract some length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When dwelling G4, my printer is oozing, how can i stop that?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7509/when-dwelling-g4-my-printer-is-oozing-how-can-i-stop-that)

Comment: thanks for the comments and recommendation of a similar question - however that doesnt quite help. I'm asking more specifically what can be done with the v6. I understand why there is ooze and why it cant be completely stopped - but when comparing it to my cheap hotend which doesnt ooze nearly as much as the e3d v6, it takes no force to push filament through the v6 but there is some resistance pushing it through the cheap hotend at the exact same temperature and same nozzle size. the cheap hotend stops oozing very soon, the e3d just continues to drip.

Comment: Could be that the inside of the nozzle is differently machined and shaped.

Comment: Are both hotends identical? Or, is the genuine PTFE lined and the clone all-metal heat break?

Comment: my cheap one that doesnt ooze is a generic ptfe lined hotend and the one that oozes is an all metal genuine e3d v6. it oozes to the point that its unusable as the material builds up on the nozzle and leaves blobs all over the print.

Comment: please share a photo of the setup and the retraction settings for each hotend. Note it is always advised to have all hotends be of the same design to make settings easier.

Comment: I will get a picture up soon. The plan is to have both the same, but I wanted to try the e3d v6 first as I've heard great things about it and terrible things about it (jamming, oozing, etc)

Comment: Ahhh, well, the e3D v6 is an all-metal hotend, which has some benefits and problems. if you want to work with a hotend that is PLA only, the e3d Lite6 is an option for a lined, not-all-metal hotend. It is easier to work with at times.