# How to prevent stringing with 0.25 mm nozzle?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anycubic-i3-mega

When I print with a 0.4  mm nozzle I have no problem with stringing at all but because I need a more detailed print I must use a 0.25 mm nozzle.

I use Ultimaker Cura and an Anycubic i3 Mega.

What i tried so far:

- Enable/Disable Z hop
- Tried different retraction distance and speed.
- Tried with lower temperature
- Different wall thickness

If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! Have you changed the nozzle size within cura?

Comment: Yes i have changed the line width to 0.25

Comment: Nozzle width and line width are separate.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should change the **nozzle diameter** setting, not just the line width setting, in Cura. Both are involved in determining extrusion. Line width can be less than or greater than nozzle size, but setting it much larger or smaller is not going to work well.

I suspect your main problem, though, is print speed. The area of the 0.25 mm nozzle orifice is only 39% of the area of an 0.4 mm nozzle orifice, bounding the material extrusion rate **at best** at 39% of what you could get with the larger nozzle (in practice it will be even lower due to complex fluid dynamics, probably much lower), but at the same linear print speed with narrower lines, you'll be extruding (or trying to extrude) 62.5% as much material per unit time. Now, if that much material can't actually make it out of the nozzle, pressure builds up between the extruder gear and the nozzle, and stringing is the result.

So, try lowering the print speed. **A lot** at first. If that solves the problem, gradually increase it until you find the limit. Increasing retraction and temperature may help you push it a little further. See my question and self-answer on stringing with flexible filaments, which might give you some ideas on other things to try:

[Avoiding stringing with flexible filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/8512/11157)

Answer (score 1):

What worked well for me in avoiding stringing is to increase the travel move speeds significantly, disable Z-hop and to decrease printing temperature

Comment: These are definitely both good ideas. At first I was confused that z-hop might help avoid stringing, since I mistakenly believed it was caused by re-melting and dragging correctly-deposited material. But after spending a lot of time on it, I found that pretty much all of it was a matter of new material coming out of the nozzle during travel or dragging *incorrectly deposited* material due to previous oozing from the nozzle.