# Slicer for 32 Bit Operating systems?

Tags: slicing

I currently only have access to an old, 32 bit OS and need to slice a couple things. While there are a lot of slicers around, most popular ones, for example Ultimaker Cura 4, need to run on a 64 bit operation system.

What somewhat recent (late 2018, 2019) options offering common abilities are there that run on older computers?

Comment: While Cura might only be shipping 64-bit binaries for Windows, you can certainly build it yourself for a 32-bit system.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Doing so needs extensive programming knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last version of Ultimaker Cura that supported 32-bit Operation Systems was [Cura 2.3.1](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/releases/tag/2.3.1) of 2016, which of course has a lot of items not yet in it and doesn't fit the demand of offering some update at worst from 2018.

32-bit support is starting to fade from the support of projects, as 64-bit makes a lot of things much easier and faster and 32 Bit Windows likewise is pretty much a dead-end branch with Windows 7 Support being discontinued on January 14th, 2020. For example, the [Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Documentation/4.10/SlicerApplication/HardwareConfiguration#32_bit_versus_64_bit) project says on their documentation of the May 2019 4.10 version: "We do not make 32 bit builds available."

### Yet there is rescue with the Slic3r-Family!

[Slic3r](https://slic3r.org) 1.3.0 is open source, available as 32 and 64-bit versions, and was released in November 2018, making it somewhat up to date. You need to customize a lot of settings in it, but it is after all quite a powerful slicer - for which you have to [write your own Start Code](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/writing-g-code-swiping-at-start-of-print), define your filament settings and machine.

[Repetier Host 2.1.6](https://www.repetier.com) is likewise a 32-bit application. It's technically a console with slicing features and uses one of several engines to slice - including the Slic3r and Slic3r Prusa Edition engines, which run on 32-bit. In comparison to Slic3r, I find its UI for placing items a little more user-friendly. It does pull the settings from Slic3r, if you have that installed.

[Slic3r Prusa Edition/PrusaSlicer](https://www.prusa3d.com/prusaslicer/) is a derivate of the Slic3r project. 2.2.9 was released in December 2019. It too runs on 32 bit systems. Even [2.4.2](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/releases/download/version_2.4.2/PrusaSlicer-2.4.2+win32-202204251123.zip) of the end of 2022 has 32 bit support. It is, UI-wise, even more comfortable than Repetier Host and is somewhat similar to Ultimaker Cura 4.

Comment: To date, end of December 2022, the last 32-bit version of PrusaSlicer is [release 2.4.2](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/releases/download/version_2.4.2/PrusaSlicer-2.4.2+win32-202204251123.zip).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [C6 Slicer software](https://www.c6.fabheads.com/), which is a Cloud-based one, no need of an application version. I think they are still in development phase, but still does give some good prints.