# Recommendation for free, intuitive offline 3D modeling software for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-design, software

I've used TinkerCAD (https://www.tinkercad.com/) and was able to easily model objects for 3D printing, despite having no prior experience in 3D modeling.
However it needs to be connected to the internet to work, which is not always available at my location.
At minimum, I need an ability to create solid shapes and holes, and with resize, align and rotate options.

Is there an equivalent program that's free, with a similar intuitive interface as TinkerCAD, and works completely offline?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "Recommendation-based questions really are off-topic, unless very specific indeed - and even then they may still end up being closed."

Comment: For software recommendations, consider to move or repost to the Software Recommendations SE. Other 3D printer forums are suitable as well, but be prepared to be deluged with a suggestion for every program out there!

Comment: You could start with some of the recommendations from [all3dp.com](https://all3dp.com/1/best-free-3d-modeling-software-for-beginners/).

Comment: Without a very specific niche requirement such as [*2018-20 Slicer running on a 32 bis OS*](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11750) or similar narrow band, this is highly opinion based and will never have a "best" answer.

Comment: Thanks @agarza. I'll try out a bunch of 3D CAD software.If this question doesn't get shut down, I'll at least post which one worked best from the point of view of someone with limited experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From trying out several alternatives (Fusion 360, Wings 3D, Blender, and others), the closest free offline equivalent to TinkerCAD turned out to be OpenSCAD.

It has nowhere near the same level of intuition,
but based on info from two tutorials ("[OpenSCAD Tutorial - Beginners Quickstart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTCu2hCuqfg)", "[OpenSCAD - Model a Bearing in less than ten minutes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSqpdPrJAqg)"), OpenSCAD was able to fulfill the minimum requirements that were needed from TinkerCAD most quickly, i.e.,"*...ability to create solid shapes and holes, and with resize, align and rotate options*"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be fewer answers than we expect.
Personally free software wise I like FreeCAD but it is not similar to the simple shapes of tinkercad at all and not intuitive.

I did know someone who used something from https://www.xyzprinting.com that was very similar to the tinkercad stuff, but eventually ran into limitations and switched to more advanced software anyway.