# Are there any free scanning programs available?

Tags: software, scanning

I keep looking around for 3D scanning software but can't find anything I like. Any suggestions? I'm more looking for a free app so I can use my android phone, but am open to desktop based solutions too.

Comment: You are going to get a lot of different answers/opinions with that kind of question. I would suggest narrowing it down with more specific information that you are needing/wanting.

Comment: This could be good as a community wiki, because the answers change over time.  Also tagged as [canonical] so future duplicates can be closed and aimed at this "authorative" question.

Comment: that's actually a good idea

Comment: in contrast to the [32-Bit-Slicers of post-2018](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11751/8884) (which is a *very* tiny number and very few will be developed anymore), this is entirely opinion based.

Comment: @Criggie - tell us more about this [canonical] tag (do you have a link?)... we don't have one yet, although we do have a [knowledge-base] tag, is that the same thing? I thought that there was a meta post about our knowledge base, but I can't find it.

Comment: In case this question does get closed for being a request for software recommendation, there is actually (rather ironically) a [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site on Stack Exchange, where presumably they *only* accept shopping type questions...

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Meshroom

https://alicevision.org/

Meshroom can take any number of overlapping photographs and turn them into a 3D model. Those pictures can be taken from any phone, or even a drone. For best results, you will need to know the make/model and sensor size of the camera.

Works on Windows/Linux and requires a CUDA compatible video card

**Resources**

- https://alicevision.org/#meshroom
- [Prusa Blog on Meshroom](https://blog.prusaprinters.org/photogrammetry-2-3d-scanning-simpler-better-than-ever_29393/)

### 2. ADOP

https://github.com/darglein/ADOP

ADOP is a neural network similar to Meshroom that can combine photos into a 3D model, however, it has a very impressive ability to generate highly accurate data from just a few pictures. It also provides a virtual reality viewer.

Works on Linux/Windows. Does require some familiarity compiling code

**Resources**

- ADOP featured on [2-minute papers YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZ_5TPWGPQI)
- https://github.com/darglein/ADOP

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [SCANN3D](https://scann3d.it/). It is available on Android but I don't know if it is for desktop too.

Comment: Link is dead, presumably it is this: https://sourceforge.net/software/product/SCANN3D/ or here on [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartmobilevision.scann3d&hl=en&gl=US)

Comment: Also, if you [edit] and add why you like the app and its features, then that *might* be useful.