# 32-bit slicer software?

Tags: creality-ender-3, slic3r

I purchased an Ender 3 v2 3D printer just before Christmas and I have the software on my laptop I was going to use for it. My laptop is a Windows 10 32-bit operating system.

However, the Creality slicer software v4.8 only works on 64-bit systems. Does anyone know what version I can download to use on my 32-bit Windows 10 laptop, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Slicer for 32 Bit Operating systems?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11750/slicer-for-32-bit-operating-systems)

Comment: To date, end of December 2022, the last 32-bit version of PrusaSlicer is [release 2.4.2](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/releases/download/version_2.4.2/PrusaSlicer-2.4.2+win32-202204251123.zip).

Comment: You don't have to stick with Creality Slicer. You can use other popular slicers with your Ender-3 v2. I'm currently using PrusaSlicer 2.4.0 on my 32-bit laptop.

Comment: how old is your laptop? 32-bit computers have been obsolete since about 2007. You might have a 32-bit OS installed on a 64-bit laptop and then you should install the 64-bit OS instead