# Flashforge Adventurer 3, filament problem

Tags: filament, flashforge-adventurer-3

I have just bought my son a used Flashforge Adventurer 3 and the man who sold it to me said he had a bit of trouble with the filament starting to come out before it touches the print bed but if you just grab the filament with a pair of tweezers right before it hits the bed it prints fine.

Does anyone have a way to fix the problem I'm a 3D printing virgin and it is being delivered today so I don't want it to be a problem for my boy.

Comment: Are you referring to the oozing or priming prior to the laying down the first layer?

Answer (score 0):

Most printers ooze material when heating up (no extruder rotation). Usually this is related to the left over amount of filament left in the nozzle/heat break. Tweezers are effective to remove the oozed material. This can also be deliberate, then it is called priming (extruder rotates).

You can retract filament after printing your product (in your end G-code script), this will reduce the amount of material it oozes during warm-up of the next print. If it is part of the priming, you could improve your start G-code to optimize priming (different location and height). Furthermore, you can also [swipe](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/writing-g-code-swiping-at-start-of-print) at the beginning (adapting start G-code in your slicer).